# PHP pages behind asp.net forums authentication

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, iis-6, forms-authentication

Been searching for an answer to this but read some conflicting reports.

I have a asp.net website with forms authentication setup and I'm adding some php pages to a subfolder within the site. I want these pages to follow the same authentication as the rest of the site, ie be bounced to my asp.net login form if not logged in.

Currently if I access a file `http://localhost/test/test.php` it is serving it even if I'm not logged in. However if I just browse to the folder `http://localhost/test/` it does bounce me to login page. Guess I need to force these PHP pages through the asp pipeline but is this possible in classic mode / iis6?

Comment: Are you saying that using `http://localhost/test/` in the browser auto redirects you?

Comment: I also don't think PHP can use a session that is set within ASP. Why don't you continue to use ASP instead of PHP for this task?

Comment: thats correct `http://localhost/test/` is redirecting me to my login page. The reason its PHP is I'm integrating a wordpress blog

Comment: I think you're better off writing the log-in state into a record in the DB and check it in the PHP script as well. But this is not fool-proof as it relies on the user logging out as well.

Comment: Hmm I could but forms auth does all that for me I'm sure there must be  a way of applying it to php

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got this working by doing the following:

1. Convert folder containing my app into an application in iis 6 manager
2. Click Configuration in the Directory tab of the properties dialog for the above folder and define a wildcard mapping pointing to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll